# Get the Value from a Slider when the slider is moved (in Limesurvey)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-slider, limesurvey

i'm working with Limesurvey and Javascript for the first time. I want to get the value of a slider everytime it is moved. I didn't know how to do this properly. Until now it got something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#slider-handle-576875X1492X18245SQ001" ).click(function() {
        alert($( ".ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" ).slider( "value"));
    });
 });
```

And this works so far, that everytime i click the slider, i get a alert, but it only gives me  [objetc Object] and not the value.

I'm not sure how i can get the value, because if i look at the html code of the slider, the value (at this moment 14) is stored anywhere, just in  percentage via  `style="left: 46.666666666666664%;">`

I  just post it here so you can have a look!

```
<div id="slider-576875X1492X18245SQ001" class="ui-slider-1 ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <div id="slider-left-576875X1492X18245SQ001" class="slider_showmin">0</div>
  <div class="slider_callout" id="slider-callout-576875X1492X18245SQ001" style="left: 93.32386016845703px;">14</div>
  <div class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="slider-handle-576875X1492X18245SQ001" style="left: 46.666666666666664%;"></div>
  <div id="slider-right-576875X1492X18245SQ001" class="slider_showmax">30</div>
  </div>

  <div id="slider-left-576875X1492X18245SQ001" class="slider_showmin">0</div>

  <div class="slider_callout" id="slider-callout-576875X1492X18245SQ001" style="left: 93.32386016845703px;">14</div>

  <div class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="slider-handle-576875X1492X18245SQ001" style="left: 46.666666666666664%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you are not using the proper id and function to get the value. I guess the following code should work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#slider-handle-576875X1492X18245SQ001" ).click(function() {
        alert($( "#slider-callout-576875X1492X18245SQ001" ).html());
    });
 });
```

Hope this helps!

cheers!